# Angular directive bug causes a wrong assignment

Tags: angular, typescript

I normally split the problem into the user perspective and the developer perspective.

**User's perspective:**

When I click on an anchor tag, it receives a blue highlight. What also happens is that the "Add" button changes into "Update". That's what I want. However, when I click on "Delete" or more precisely, when I click on "delete" and none of the anchor tags have the blue highlight, the "Update" button should go back to "Add". What happens is that it does NOT change back to "Add" and continues on "Update" I'll provide screenshots to further illustrate my example.

Before anything is clicked:
[image]

After clicking on an anchor tag:
[image]

After pressing "Delete":

[image]

Notice how "Tomatoes" is not highlighted and the green button is still on "Updated". That's the problem.

**Developer's Perspective:**

Here in shopping list, we have the Shopping List Component that is responsible for displaying the items. Take a look at the commented code.

```html
<app-shopping-edit></app-shopping-edit>
    <hr>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <!-- 
        In the anchor tag, we toggle between the active class. The toggling between the active class
        works perfectly fine. The appToggleActiveClass directive is responsible for selecting particular 
        anchor tags. It is also responsible for deleting directives. Keep in mind the blue highlight is
        from the "active" class that we add dynamically. 
      -->
      <a
        class="list-group-item"
        appToggleActiveClass
        style="cursor: pointer"
        (click) = "onSelectItem(i)"
        *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients; let i = index">
        {{ ingredient.name }} ({{ ingredient.amount }})
      </a>
    </ul>
```

Shopping List Component TS:

```js
export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck, AfterViewChecked {
  // In order to access our directive in our template
  @ViewChildren(ToggleActiveClassDirective) ToggleDirective: ToggleActiveClassDirective[];
  // The ingredients that are to be displayed
  ingredients: Ingredient[]
  // Whether the button says "Add" or "Update". This is very important
  editMode = false
  // This is how we add ingredients to our list. This is works perfectly fine
  private sub: Subscription
  /* 
    This may have a role in the problem. We subscribe to the observable and we use a method in 
    ToggleDirective to delete selected lists. We're using the same directive, so I am not sure if
    that has anything to do with the problem.
  */
  private subForRemoved: Subscription

  // we inject our shoppingList Service which I will post
  constructor(private shoppingListSerivce: ShoppingList) { }

  // We select an item and we pass it on to the shopping list service.
  onSelectItem(index: number) {
    this.shoppingListSerivce.editIngredient.next(index)
    /*
      VERY IMPORTANT: This binding does not work all the time. When I click delete and there's no active
      class then for some reason, it still turns out to be true even though there are no active classes on each
      item.
    */
    this.editMode = this.ToggleDirective.some((el, index, arr) => {
     return el.checkIfAnyActive()
    })
    console.log(this.editMode)
    // when the bug happens, this turns out to be true
    this.shoppingListSerivce.editMode.next(this.editMode)
   }  


  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    /* 
      I am trying to do the same thing as I did in onSelectItem() but it's 
      still giving me true when no links are clicked after I press delete.
    */
    this.editMode = this.ToggleDirective.some((el, index, arr) => {
      return el.checkIfAnyActive()
     })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ingredients = this.shoppingListSerivce.ingredients 
    // subscribing to the ingredient we get and adding it.
    this.sub = this.shoppingListSerivce.ingredientAdded.subscribe(
      (ingredient: any) => {
        if (ingredient.constructor != Array) {  
          this.shoppingListSerivce.addIngredient(ingredient);
          this.ingredients = this.shoppingListSerivce.ingredients
        }
        else {
          // this is jus resetting the ingredients
          this.shoppingListSerivce.ingredients = []
          this.ingredients = ingredient
        }
        
    }
  )

  // we subscribe to the Subject where we capture each element with the ToggleDierctive and we delete it
  this.subForRemoved = this.shoppingListSerivce.deleteShoppingIngredients.subscribe(
    // We don't really need the value
  (value) => {
    this.ToggleDirective.forEach(el => el.deleteItem())
  })
  }

  // unsubscribing to observables to avoid memory leaks
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
    this.subForRemoved.unsubscribe()
    }

  

  // making sure that ingredients defined above is always the same as the ingredients in the shopping service
  ngDoCheck() {
    this.ingredients = this.shoppingListSerivce.ingredients
    
  }


}
```

Let's take a look at the ShoppingList Service

```js
export class ShoppingList {

      // Default set of ingredients that are to be ordered when you open the page
      ingredients: Ingredient[] = [
        new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
        new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 10),
      ];

      // We use this whenever we want to add ingredient/s.
      ingredientAdded = new Subject<Ingredient[] | Ingredient>();

      // Whenever we want to delete the ingredient
      deleteShoppingIngredients = new Subject<String>()

      // when we want to edit an ingredient
      editIngredient = new Subject<number>()

      // whether we can edit ingredients
      editMode = new Subject<boolean>()

      getIngredient(index: number) {
        return this.ingredients[index]
      }

      addIngredient(ingredient: Ingredient) {
        this.ingredients.push(ingredient);
      }

      addIngredients(ingredients: Ingredient[]) {
        this.ingredients.push(...ingredients)
      }

      // We update a particular ingredient using the index with a new ingredient we pass on
      updateIngredient(index: number, ing: Ingredient) {
        this.ingredients[index] = ing
      }


   
}
```

Shopping List EDIT template:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
          <!-- 
            As you can see here, editMode determines whether we are on Update or Add. For some reason
            after we delete, it's always true. 
          -->
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">{{ editMode ? 'Update' : 'Add'}}</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click) = "deleteItems()">Delete</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click) = "clearItems()">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Shopping List EDIT TS:

```js
 export class ShoppingEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck {
  @ViewChildren(ToggleActiveClassDirective) ToggleDirective: ToggleActiveClassDirective[]
  @ViewChild('form') form
  // the 'sub' subscription allows us to subscribe to the edits made
  sub: Subscription
  // this tells us whether we are allowed to edit or not
  subEditMode: Subscription
  // If true, then allowed to edit. If false, no edit
  editMode: boolean = false
  // index of the item we're editing
  editItemIndex: number
  // what we're editing
  editedItem: Ingredient
  

  constructor(private shoppingListService: ShoppingList) { }

   ngOnInit() {
    // we got the index from onSelectItem remember. 
    this.sub = this.shoppingListService.editIngredient.subscribe((index) => {
      this.editItemIndex = index
      this.editMode = this.ToggleDirective.some((el, index, value) => {
        return el.checkIfAnyActive()
      })
      this.editedItem = this.shoppingListService.getIngredient(index)
      this.form.setValue({
        name: this.editedItem.name,
        amount: this.editedItem.amount
      })
    })
  }

  // even trying to make sure that we're getting the right values, no luck
  ngDoCheck(): void {
    this.subEditMode = this.shoppingListService.editMode.subscribe((value) => {
      this.editMode = value
    })
  }

  // just unsubscribing to avoid memory leaks
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
    this.subEditMode.unsubscribe()
  }

  // 
  onAddOrEditItem() {
    const ingName = this.form.value.name
    const ingAmount = this.form.value.amount
    const newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingName, ingAmount);
    // most code is irrelevent, the only code that's relevent is the editMode
    if (this.editMode) {
      console.log(this.editItemIndex)
      this.shoppingListService.updateIngredient(this.editItemIndex, newIngredient)
    }
    else {
      this.shoppingListService.ingredientAdded.next(newIngredient)

    }
    this.form.reset()
  }


    // Just simply passing an empty array to clear items
    clearItems() {
    this.shoppingListService.ingredientAdded.next([])
    }

    // this method could be a part of the problem
    deleteItems() {
      // it could be this first line because we use the directive when we subscribe to it.
    this.shoppingListService.deleteShoppingIngredients.next('delete')
    this.form.reset()

  }

}
```

I'll provide my whole GitHub repo in case anyone wants to play around with it. Keep in mind only the shopping list service in services and the shopping list folder are important. That's if, you choose to play around with the repo. https://github.com/yousefmarey12/CourseShoppingProject

Comment: Why do you use a directive for that ? Instead use the selection list from angular's CDK ?

Comment: @MGX , I'm new to Angular and don't know what that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to Angular I strongly recommend training with their Heroes tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes.

Otherwise you will find yourself repeatedly posting questions without fully learning Angular.

Regarding your question: in **shopping-edit.component.ts** method **deleteItems** (and in **clearItems** as well) add:

```
this.editMode = false;
```

This will take you out of edit mode and the button will say **Add**.